# How do I build a react-native app so that it runs as an ipad app on an ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, react-native

My app looks terrible on an ipad because it's running as an iphone-emulated app instead of an ipad app.

What do I need to do in my code to deal with the possibility that it may be running on an ipad?

How do I build the app with react-native so that it will install on an ipad and run as an ipad app?

Is this possible to do without xcode?

I'm running `react-native run-ios` with an iPad Air simulator running. Perhaps I need to set up a scheme and call it with `--scheme`?

Comment: please can i see your code?

Comment: That's a little vague, what part of the code is relevant?

Comment: are you using flex for views or hard coded values of height and screen ?

Comment: Under Deployment Info, is Devices targeted to Universal?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think you have not kept your Devices in Xcode as Universal. Go to Xcode click on the project name. In the target section go to Deployment Info. Set Devices to Universal.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 12, it's in a section called Deployment Info".
Checking the "iPad" checkbox will automatically set the `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` setting to `1,2`.

[image: Xcode 12]

Answer (score 7):

you can use this command

> react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"

Visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios.html

Answer (score 7):

As of Xcode 9.3.1, you have to go to Build Settings and select **Targeted Device Family** `1,2` if you want to support both the iPad and iPhone.

[image: React Native iPhone iPad rendering support]

Comment: When I followed what @atitpatel suggested it automatically changed the "Target Device Family" to "1,2"

Comment: it now says "iPhone", "iPad" and "iPhone, iPad"

Answer (score 3):

for new version of XCODE 14.3
press the + button and add the device you want (Ipad) here for example
then you can run : npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad (10th
generation)"
[image: press the + button and add the device you want]